# Links not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can anyone see why my links in my header are not working for the home and contact us page.

http://www.rg3fitness.com/

Can't seem to see any problems with the code. They are hard coded.

Comment: Which links are not working? It would be preferable if you could post some code here, for this to be useful to other people.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rg3fitness.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index: 100;` to `.home-contact`

```
.home-contact {
float: left;
position: relative;
left: 690px;
top: 10px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

...
now add

`z-index`  on your `.home-contact` class

```
.home-contact{
z-index:11;
}
```